# me aparece problema de version de plugins faltante en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

```
estoy tratando de compilar un programa  y me aparece esto:

    Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.mycompany:CelsiusConverterProject:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
    'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin is missing.
    'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin is missing.
    'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin is missing.

    It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.

    For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.


    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Building CelsiusConverterProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ CelsiusConverterProject ---
```

Y este es pom.xml que esta en el directorio de mi proyecto:
  
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0
        com.mycompany
        CelsiusConverterProject
        1.0-SNAPSHOT
        jar
        
            UTF-8
            14
            14
        
    
    que necesito hacer para que desaparezca este mensaje?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor pon tu pom como texto, no todo el mundo es capaz de ver las imágenes

Answer (score 0):

Allí mismo te dice que te falta:

```
build.plugins.plugin.version
```

Tus plugins no tienen una versión especificada

Y también te dice que plugins no lo tienen, en conreto:

[maven-source-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-source-plugin), [maven-javadoc-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-javadoc-plugin) y [maven-deploy-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-deploy-plugin)

Ejemplo de problema:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Solución:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: como puedo solucionarlo? siguiendo las rtas de varios sitios en Internet, veo que tengo que buscar el archivo pom.xml y agregar esas etiquetas que faltan, pero yo no las veo en ningún lado de ese archivo¡

Comment: normalmente está en la raíz de tu proyecto.

Comment: Ahh viendo que estás en netbeans hay hasta abajo por lo general una carpeta qeu dice algo así como project configuration files, allí debería de aparecer, si no lo ves, abre tu explorador de ficheros local y ve a la carpeta donde está tu proyecto.

Comment: Por eso.tambien fui a ese que me aparece en el navegador de netbeans.le di click, y me aparece exactamente lo mismo que me aparece cuando le doy click en el archivo con el mismo nombre(que en este caso es pom.xml)pero tampoco menciona algun maven-source-plugin o alguno de los otras etiquetas de las falta describir sus versiones

Comment: Agrega tu pom, hay dos formas de corregirlo, una es poniendole a tu pom explícitamente el plugin como lo hice yo y la otra es mediante una propiedad

Comment: Hay otro detalle,cuando descargue el ejecutable de netbeans -mi pc me dijo que no se podia instalar desde el ejecutable,entonces lo que hice,fue que descargue las dos carpetas que llamaban mirror(y cuyos nombres eran "bin"y "source" con eso, lo que hice fue que las copié en mi carpeta de archivos de programa en el disco c y desde ahí ejecuté el programa de netbeans

Comment: Ese parece ser tema para otra pregunta.

Comment: Aokey.entonces borro ?lo que hago es que borro todo lo q me aparezca en ese archivo llamado pom.xml y copio el que tengo que no habla nada de los plugings faltantes? O como?

Comment: Como dije, Agrega tu pom a la pregunta

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>CelsiusConverterProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-

Comment: 8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>

Comment: como dije a la pregunta, no acá